# VHDX Drive keeps unmounting itself

Tags: mount, 22.04, hyper-v

We have an Ubuntu VM setup on HyperV. There is an additional drive setup for a specific purpose. Every so often, or perhaps only or mainly when the VM is restarted, the drive unmounts itself. Is there a reason that this would happen and is there a way this can be monitored currently, we rely on the users telling us data is unavailable before we know it has been unmounted again. The command I am running each time to mount it again is:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /NASData
```

The VM has all the latest updates and is running 22.04